# Using overly on the photo of country flags

Tags: html, css

I have this picture of country flags. **http://i.hizliresim.com/e7Y5dm.png**

I want to manipulate this photo in a way I can show them in 120x60px format. Currently I can only do Afghanistan but I can't apply it to the rest of the flags. I want to show Albania if I give 120px margin to somewhere but couldn't find out where. Thanks.

**http://jsfiddle.net/JA97b/**

```
#flag
{
    width: 120px;
    height: 60px;
    background-image: url(http://i.hizliresim.com/e7Y5dm.png);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're looking for `background-position`.
Have a look at the updated <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JA97b/1/)**</kbd>.